# Absolute difference with each element of array for each element in linear time

Tags: time-complexity, array-difference

Given an array

```
a[4]={2,5,8,9};
```

The absolute differences with respect to each element would be

```
(3,6,7,3,4,1)
abs(2-5)=3
abs(2-8)=6
abs(2-9)=7
abs(5-8)=3
abs(5-9)=4
abs(8-9)=1
```

Is it possible to find this in linear time? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you have to list all differences or just sum them up or something? What have you tried?

Comment: I want a list of all the differences. I could only think of the naive approach uptil now. I want to know if it is possible to do it in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

If n is the number of elements, you have to do (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 comparisons, and you can obviously do it in that, so it looks like theta(n^2) comparisons.  If you could do it in linear time, then bubble sort would be linear (it's n^2).

Comment: I know that and I've done that. I just want to know if there is any way of doing it in linear time